# Using Dependency Injected Fields in Ember Controllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How do I use a dependency injected field in another field within the ember controller in 2.x Ember?

For instance, I have

```
  export default Ember.Controller.extend({
     session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
     user: this.get('session').username
```

How is `user` able to access the lazily computed values of `session`?

I noticed that the case above doesn't work as I believe the value of `session` has been computed yet?

I could use a computed property but I use `user` as a value in `input` and I am merely setting a base value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it seems like you could use computed property function (I usually handle it this way when it comes to DI):

```
user: Ember.computed.oneWay('session.username')
```

Or simpler, `alias`:

```
user: Ember.computed.alias('session.username')
```